# JHipster POST entity ID

Tags: rest, post, spring-boot, postman, jhipster

I'm trying to post the following object via JSON through JHipster API:

```
{
  "avaliacao": 3,
  "dataHoraCancelamento": "2017-08-18T18:15:39.380Z",
  "dataHoraEntrega": "2017-08-18T18:15:39.380Z",
  "dataHoraPedido": "2017-08-18T18:15:39.380Z",
  "dataHoraPrevisao": "2017-08-18T18:15:39.380Z",
  "dataHoraPronto": "2017-08-18T18:15:39.380Z",
  "numero": "string",
  "observacoesCliente": "string",
  "observacoesRestaurante": "string",
  "restauranteId": 1051,
  "shoppingId": 1151,
  "status": "EM_CRIACAO",
  "tempoPreparacao": 6,
  "total": 4
}
```

but I manage to save it only from the application form on the frontend. When I try to do a POST via cURL or Postman I get a

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

with the following stacktrace on the backend:

```
Exception in br.com.myapp.web.rest.PedidoResource.createPedido() with 
cause = 'org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
execute statement' and exception = 'could not execute statement; SQL [n/a];
constraint ["FK_PEDIDO_RESTAURANTE_ID: PUBLIC.PEDIDO FOREIGN
KEY(RESTAURANTE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.RESTAURANTE(ID) (1051)"; SQL statement
[23506-195]]; 

nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
could not execute statement
```

P.S.: I acknowledge this error references the two entity fields ("restauranteId" and "shoppingId") I have on my payload, indeed if I post the object without these fields it works.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message its means that the JSON object that are you posting is missing information with regard to the entities which are referenced. For a proper JSON object have a look at the swagger documentation in your app or inspect with the web tools of your web browser the payload which is done when are you making the post over the browser.